# What is wrong in my smarty loop

Tags: smarty, smarty3

```
{section name=i loop=(($data|count)/2) start=0}
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    {section name=ii loop=i start=(i+2)}
    <a href="#" data-role="button" name="buttons" rel="{$page['user'][ii]}">{$user['page'][$page['user'][ii]]}</a>
    {/section}
</div>
```

Problem is somewhre near `{section name=ii loop=i start=(i+2)}` because `<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">` is empty in source.

Comment: What does your $data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{section name=i loop=(($data|@count)/2) start=0}
```

instead of

```
{section name=i loop=(($data|count)/2) start=0}
```